# Adding antialiasing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to using antialiasing but I don't why it isn't working:

```
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
Pen r = new Pen(Color.YellowGreen, 3);
Graphics b = panel2.CreateGraphics();
b.DrawEllipse(pen, 6, 0, 90, 90);
b.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
b.DrawLine(r, new Point(50, 90), new Point(50, 0));
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First it should be noted that the `Graphics` object does not **contain** any graphics; it is a **tool** that lets you draw onto a related bitmap, including a control's surface. Therefore changing any of its properties, like the `SmoothingMode` **only** influences graphics you draw **from then on**, not anything you have drawn **before**..

The circle certainly **would** have antialised pixels **if** you would draw it **after** setting the `SmoothingMode` from its default `None` to `AntiAlias`.

The Line is **vertical**, so it doesn't need antialiasing except at its ends, where there **is** some. But if you tilt it or move it to a **non-integer** position anti-aliasing will show!

Let's modify your code a little and look closely at the result:

```
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
Pen r = new Pen(Color.YellowGreen, 3);
Graphics b = panel2.CreateGraphics();
b.DrawEllipse(pen, 6, 6, 90, 90);
b.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
b.DrawLine(r, new Point(50, 90), new Point(50, 0));

b.DrawLine(r, new Point(60, 90), new Point(70, 0));
b.DrawLine(r, new PointF(40.5f, 90), new PointF(40.5f, 0));
b.DrawEllipse(pen, 6, 6, 30, 30);
```

[image][image]

The smaller circle has many gray pixels and even the original green line has a lighter top end. The two new lines are fully anti-aliased now, one because it is tilted,  the other because it sits 'between' pixels.

Btw: If it is turned on you will **also** see anti-alising when your `Pen.Width` is **even** or when it is a **non-integer** number. The reason for the latter should be obvious; the former comes from the [`PenAlignment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z62ath7a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. Its default `Center` tries to center the pen, but not at the pixel boundary but at the center of the coordinate pixels. Therefore only an **uneven** width will completely fill the pixels and not cause anti-aliasing. For **closed shapes** you can change this behaviour by changing the `Pen.Alignment` to `Inset`:

> This property determines how the Pen draws closed curves and
>   polygons. The PenAlignment enumeration specifies five values;
>   however, only two values—Center and Inset—will change the appearance
>   of a drawn line. Center is the default value for this property and
>   specifies that the width of the pen is centered on the outline of the
>   curve or polygon. A value of Inset for this property specifies that the
>   width of the pen is inside the outline of the curve or polygon. The
>   other three values, Right, Left, and Outset, will result in a pen that
>   is centered.
>
> A Pen that has its alignment set to Inset will yield unreliable
>   results, sometimes drawing in the inset position and sometimes in the
>   centered position.Also, an inset pen cannot be used to draw compound
>   lines and cannot draw dashed lines with Triangle dash caps.

**PS:** The question was not about how to draw **properly**, so let me just note that you **never** ought to do it using `control.CreateGraphics` as this will always only result in **non-persistent** graphics. Instead you need to use the `Paint` event and its `e.Graphics` object..