# Graphics.DrawImage() clips image when using RotateTransform()

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, drawimage

I have following code to draw my `border2.bmp` in 4 direction

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap border = new Bitmap("border2.bmp");
    int borderThick = border.Height;

    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Size region = g.VisibleClipBounds.Size.ToSize();

    Rectangle desRectW = new Rectangle(0, 0, region.Width - borderThick, borderThick);

    // 1. LEFT - RIGHT border
    g.TranslateTransform(30, 30);
    g.DrawImage(border, desRectW, desRectW, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    // 2. UP - BUTTOM border
    g.ResetTransform();
    g.TranslateTransform(50, 50);
    g.RotateTransform(90);
    g.DrawImage(border, desRectW, desRectW, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    // 3. RIGHT-LEFT border
    g.ResetTransform();
    g.TranslateTransform(100, 100);
    g.RotateTransform(180);
    g.DrawImage(border, desRectW, desRectW, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    // 4. BOTTOM - UP border
    g.ResetTransform();
    g.TranslateTransform(150, 150);
    g.RotateTransform(270);
    g.DrawImage(border, desRectW, desRectW, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
```

My original image is:

[image]

But the result of rotations are not exactly as I expected. 90 degrees is missing the first red line, 270 degrees is missing first black column, and 180 degrees is missing both.

Like image I attached:

[image]

PS: you can get `border2.bmp` at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtgGA.png

Edit:
I tried `g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;` as @Peter Duniho comment, but I found it also does't draw correctly.
Example: 4 line is not starting at same position as we expect.

```
g.TranslateTransform(50, 50);

// LEFT - RIGHT border
g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, 0, 0, 100, 0);

// UP - BOTTOM border
g.RotateTransform(90);
g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Blue)), 0, 0, 100, 0);

// RIGHT-LEFT border
g.RotateTransform(90);
g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Green)), 0, 0, 100, 0);

// BOTTOM - UP border
g.RotateTransform(90);
g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Gray)), 0, 0, 100, 0);
```

Comment: System.Drawing uses floating point math internally, that makes it suffer from off-by-one errors when a floating point value is rounded to an integral pixel.  The default value of Graphics.PixelOffsetMode was an unlucky choice, you'll have to change it to get rid of these rounding artifacts.

Comment: @HansPassant : The starting coordinate is changed after doing RotateTransform. I have just added an example.

Comment: Looking at your screenshot, this is clearly not your problem, but you still are missing one crucial step: you __need__ to make sure your image has the same __resolution__ as your monitor. It has 96dpi; my monitor has 120dpi and without correcting for that the image looks like shite, with or without rotation.. Insert this after loading the image: `using (Graphics gr = this.CreateGraphics())   img.SetResolution(gr.DpiX, gr.DpiY);` !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't really explain why this happens, except that any graphics API is necessarily going to include optimizations which may lead to imprecise behaviors at times and it seems that you are running into such a situation here.

In your particular example, the problem can be corrected by adding the following statement to the code, before you draw the images:

```
g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
```

Setting it to `Half` will also work. It is equivalent to `HighQuality` (or technically, `HighQuality` is equivalent to it…but I find `HighQuality` more descriptive in the code :) ).

This will slow the rendering of the bitmap down somewhat, but probably not in a way that is perceptible to your users.

While the .NET documentation isn't very helpful in terms of describing this setting, the native Win32 docs for the same feature has *slightly* more detail:
[PixelOffsetMode enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534169(v=vs.85).aspx). From the description, one can infer that with the logical center of the pixel at (0,0), it's possible to lose a pixel on one edge when rotating (and/or gain a pixel on another edge). Switching to `Half` fixes this.

Comment: I think, they being equivalent anyway, using `PixelOffsetModeHalf` is a little clearer. The explanation is quite interesting and understanding what the coordinates mean goes beyond `DrawImage` and rotations. I found the [same problem applies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094055/adding-antialiasing/36095479#36095479) to things as simple as a `DrawLine` with a `Pen` creating anti-aliased pixels or not, depending e.g. on the `Pen` havig an odd or even `Width`..

Comment: PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality also cause some un-expected result in others situation
Example:
`g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, 0, 0, 100, 0);
g.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, 0, 1, 100, 1);`
You will see it draw only blue line at first row.

Comment: Please see the explanation on the answer to the different question @TaW provided a link to (in the comment above). Bottom line is that you will get different artifacts in different situations depending on various settings when drawing. You don't have to keep the same `PixelOffsetMode` value when drawing lines as when drawing rotated bitmaps; just adjust the settings as needed to get the results you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to account some things.

(1) `RotateTransforms` applies rotation at the current **origin** (as explained in the `Matrix.Rotate` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix.rotate(v=vs.110).aspx)

(2) The default [MatrixOrder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrixorder(v=vs.110).aspx) (when not specified by using the overrides with the additional argument) is `Prepend`. Which means in your case the resulting transformation is rotate, then translate.

For instance, if you put this code inside the paint event:

```
var g = e.Graphics;
var loc = new Point(128, 128);
var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 64, 16);

g.ResetTransform();
g.TranslateTransform(loc.X, loc.Y);
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, rect);

g.ResetTransform();
g.TranslateTransform(loc.X, loc.Y);
g.RotateTransform(90);
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, rect);

g.ResetTransform();
g.TranslateTransform(loc.X, loc.Y);
g.RotateTransform(180);
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, rect);

g.ResetTransform();
g.TranslateTransform(loc.X, loc.Y);
g.RotateTransform(270);
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Magenta, rect);
```

you'll get this

[image]

The blue rectangle is not rotated. Now pin virtually the origin (the upper left point) and start rotating clockwise. You'll see that it will exactly match the Red (90), Green (180) and Magenta (270) rectangles.

What all that means is that if you want to form a rectangle, you need to apply additional offset (translation) to the rotated rectangles. It depends how you want to handle the overlapping areas, but for the sample if we want to concat the Red rectangle right to the Blue one, we need to add the Blue rectangle Width + the original rectangle Height in the X direction. For other rotated rectangles you can apply similar additional offset to X, Y or both.

To complete the sample, if we modify the code like this

```
var g = e.Graphics;
var loc = new Point(128, 128);
var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 64, 16);

g.ResetTransform();
g.TranslateTransform(loc.X, loc.Y);
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, rect);

g.ResetTransform();
g.TranslateTransform(loc.X + rect.Width + rect.Height, loc.Y);
g.RotateTransform(90);
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, rect);

g.ResetTransform();
g.TranslateTransform(loc.X + rect.Width + rect.Height, loc.Y + rect.Width + rect.Height);
g.RotateTransform(180);
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, rect);

g.ResetTransform();
g.TranslateTransform(loc.X, loc.Y + rect.Width + rect.Height);
g.RotateTransform(270);
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Magenta, rect);
```

the new result will be

[image]

Once you understand all that, hope you can apply the required corrections to your concrete code.